C program runs from command line, but won't by double click
I wrote a small C program as wrapper for .NET, compiled through gcc, which works on both Linux and Windows when run through the terminal or command line. Ideally I'd want it to start via double clicking it, but on Windows this does not work.
Using mingw, I can compile the same program and it will start by double click on Windows, open a terminal and run. However, this breaks the Linux executable to the point it won't even run from terminal.
Either I get "This app can't run on your PC" or "run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for Program.exe"
But if the gcc compiled version will run happily when called from command line and terminal, then what am I missing for it to run via double click on Windows? Do I have to add code or is this simply compiler flags?

What does it do when you run it from a Windows command line?

Calls up a .Net application like it is supposed to. That part works fine. It's the "double click open cmd and run" part that doesn't, because I guess Windows doesn't think it's capable of that.

who put a platform-independent tag for your question? you clearly tell different.

It's a little unclear what problem you're observing/trying to do. Are you trying to compile a single application binary that runs on both Windows and Linux?

"However, this breaks the Linux executable" How does using mingw affect your Linux executable? Do you want to use the same executable on both systems?

Does the application open any windows or does it expect to interact with a terminal?

@Gerhardh Yes. Compiling with gcc produces an executable that runs from terminal on linux and via command line on Windows, but I cannot just double click it on Windows. Using mingw to compile I can then double click it, but on Linux I get the run-detectors error.

@IanAbbott It's just a wrapper for a .Net console app, so it needs a terminal or command line to run in.

Double clicking on an executable file in a Linux desktop file manager typically doesn't launch a terminal window, although it is possible to create a .desktop file for the application that launches a terminal running a particular command. (Installing a .desktop file also allows the application to be run from an application launcher or menu.) Do you normally run the .exe file as a single-word command in the interactive shell?

@IanAbbott On Linux I usually do ./Program.exe, that works for this. So does typing Program.exe in a Windows command line. What doesn't work is double click Program.exe in Windows to open a command line and run the program. That only works when compiling with mingw, which then breaks ./Program.exe in Linux.

Does the executable compiled with mingw have the executable file mode bits set in Linux?

Does the project have the runtime identifiers set for the platforms you want to run the .exe file on (ref)?

Are you building a self-contained application or a Framework specific application? I do not think the same self-contained .exe can run on multiple platforms. You need to publish it separately for each platform. (ref)

@IanAbbott I have not set any specific compiler flags or anything specific in code. I don't know what mingw does so differently, but it seems to specifically create Windows binaries that work for that only, while gcc seems to work for both platforms. That was never the issue. It's only how to, either in code or through compiler(flags), making it double-clickable in Windows to get it to open command line and execute.

You'll have to examine the PE headers of the Windows executable. There is information in there that marks it as a console application.
